# CSS buggy in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

On the website http://thornhillss.ca/pages.php?id=7 The footer looks fine in every browser. Yet in chrome it doesn't touch the bottom of the frame. Why is that. It should be a simple fix however I just dont know why it wont work.

*It should stick to the bottom of my div. Not my page.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the div with the id "main2" isn't set to expand with the right-hand floated div. By default divs won't expand to fit floated child elements, so you need to tell it to hide overflow (which will tell it to expand to fit all child elements as long as you don't also give it a fixed height):

```
#main2 {
   width: 860px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're p.clear class has a margin on it as you're not using a reset.

If you add margin:0 to your .clear styles the margin goes away and it displays how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for it works and is awesome [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: I dont need a sticky footer I want it to stick to my content

Comment: add `clear:both;` and `min-height:300px` to `#main2` and get rid of the `<p>` with the clear both.  that will cloase the gap for you.